# How visual move the mouse cursor python (Debian/KDE/Chrome)?

Tags: python, debian, mouse, move

For some reason, **i need to !!!!visually move the mouse cursor** to a button on a web page and click on the button.
Can you please tell me how to do this in python (python 3.9.2, Debian 11, KDE Plasma 5.20, Chrome browser, selenium).
I run the python script in a console opened in KDE.
The script opens a web page in Chrome.
Now i need to move the cursor to the button and click on the button.

**How to do it?**

I've already tried different things:

**1) import pyautogui**

```
pyautogui.moveTo(mouse_x, mouse_y,duration=1) #There is no visible movement. The cursor stays where it was.
pyautogui.position() #now shows the correct cursor coordinates.
pyautogui.click() # does not work
```

**2) from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains**

```
element =driver.find_element(mconf.By.XPATH, my_xpath) #it's a button on a web page
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

There is no visible cursor movement.
Executing pyautogui.position() shows that NO MOVEMENT to element's coordinates has taken place.
The click works correctly.

**3) from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller**

```
mouse = Controller()
mouse.position =(mouse_x, mouse_y)
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
```

New coordinates shows correctly.
The click doesn't work.

Comment: Do me a favor - when you run `pyautogui.moveTo(1, 1, duration=2); pyautogui.click()`
Do you see the mouse move? I definitely do.

Comment: Also, did you install scrot and tkinter per the instructions? https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#linux

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I installed the scort according to the instructions on the link. I tried pyautogui.moveTo(1, 1, duration=2) again. Everything is the same as before. The cursor doesn't move visually :(
After working out the command, the coordinates show the correct Point (1,1).
If I navigate to an element, the click doesn't work. Haven't tried Tkinter yet. I will study how it can move the cursor.